# How to resolve unexpected new line, exec format error and permission denied when running docker-compose?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I have following docker-compose.yml file with 3 services and image is showing Dockerfile for first service which is student-service (Dockerfile for second-service which is book-service is identical). When Dockerfile is like below I get *exec format error*, when I change last line to `ENTRYPOINT "./second-service"` I get *line 2: syntax error: unexpected newline* and when i manually open Docker container and manually remove new line I get permission denied when executable is run. I am working on Windows with wsl (linux ubuntu 22.04). Can someone help I was googling for answer whole day but didn't found solution.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.20-alpine3.17
WORKDIR app
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build -o second-service
EXPOSE 8080
RUN chmod +x ./second-service
CMD ["./second-service"]
```

---- docker-compose.yml -----

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  gateway:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: nginx:1.19.8-alpine
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./Gateway/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./Gateway/api_gateway.conf:/etc/nginx/api_gateway.conf

  student-service:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: student-service:compose-build
    build:
      context: ./first-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      PORT: ${STUDENT_SERVICE_PORT}

  book-service:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: book-service:compose-build
    build:
      context: ./second-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      PORT: ${BOOK_SERVICE_PORT}
      STUDENT_SERVICE_DOMAIN: ${STUDENT_SERVICE_DOMAIN}
      STUDENT_SERVICE_PORT: ${STUDENT_SERVICE_PORT}

networks:
  backend:
    name: microservices
    driver: bridge
```

I tried everything i found on google and nothing helped just moved from one to different error.

Comment: It's not particularly clear what the error is here. Does `docker-compose build` work? What's the error output? I'm going to say 'works on my machine'™ with my own sample code

Comment: docker-compose build works but when i do docker-compose up 2 service exits with code 1 'exec format error' when last line in Dockerfile is ENTRYPOINT "./first-service", they exit with code 2 'line 2: syntax error: unexpected newline' when last line is CMD ["./first-service"] and when I manually remove newline on line 2 from binary file then they exit with code 126 'permission denied'

Comment: Your Compose file says `platform: linux/amd64`; are you actually on x86 hardware, and not something like an M1 Mac or a Raspberry Pi?  Compiled binary executables are not subject to line-ending problems and you should not hand-edit them.  You also should not need the `RUN chmod +x` line, the `go build` output should produce an executable file (provided you are building a [`main` module](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Program_execution)).

Comment: I added 'platform: linux/amd64' and 'RUN chmod +x' because I was trying different things to solve problem. I am not on M1 mac or raspberry pi and linux/amd64 is what i need i checked that. I have different solution with same docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile just witouth this few addons which is working but this one is not and i don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried to build your golang image manually and run your service inside container?

Comment: Yea i fixed it, made mistake with go package name.